# How do I enable conversion from one class to another?

Tags: c++

I have a situation where I want to allow the conversion from A to B:

```cpp
A a{4};
B b = a;
```

This is the setup:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int value)
        : member{value}
    {
    }

private:
    int member;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    explicit B(A a)
        : A{a}
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a{4};

    B b = a;
}
```

I could probably remove the `explicit` modifier in the constructor of `B`, however, Clang-Tidy complains that single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions.
What I want is *intentional* conversion from `A` to `B`, but I'm at a loss - defining a converting operator in `A` seems weird since I have to forward declare both B and its constructor, which I don't even know if is possible since `B` inherits `A`.

How do I enable this conversion?

Comment: `however, Clang-Tidy complains` So you want us to tell you to ignore clang-tidy? `What I want is intentional conversion` then be explicit - `B b = B(a);`

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want to do. I want to tell the compiler that I explicitly want to allow the conversion from B to A!

Comment: The compiler doesn't care. Clang tidy is not the compiler.

Comment: `explicit` constructors don't work with copy initialization (`=`) by the language design. But you can do `B b{a};` or `B b(a);`.

Comment: Clang-tidy is telling you that it's generally not a good idea to allow implicit conversion from one class to another like that. If that is what you want anyway, feel free to ignore clang-tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clang-Tidy complains that single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions.

Frankly, I strongly doubt that this is what clang-tidy says ("must be"). Single argument constructors that are not declared explicit are [converting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). They can be evil, because to some extend they disable type-safety.

You can enable implicit conversions, but you will also enable all unwanted implicit conversions. Consider a

```
void foo(B);
```

Without implicit conversions passing an `A` to `foo` is an error. And that is a good thing, `foo` wants a `B` not an `A`. Implicit conversions go unnoticed and can hide logic errors in code. Thats why single-argument constructors **should** be declared explicit, unless you really want them to be implcit with all the ups and downs that come with that.

TL;DR: Clang-tidys message is just a recommendation. There is nothing wrong with implicit conversions as long as you are aware of the consequences. Consider if you want it and then ignore clang-tidy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

This is indeed what clang-tidy says. Copy of problem message: `Clang-Tidy: Single-argument constructors must be marked explicit to avoid unintentional implicit conversions`

Comment: To get rid of the clang-tidy recommendation, it's possible to turn it off by changing the function declaration line to: `B(A a) // NOLINT(google-explicit-constructor)`

Comment: @glennib ok, I never used clang-tidy so I wasnt sure. Though if it really says "must be" then I'd expect that somewhere in their documentation they mention that implicit conversions are disallowed, because indeed it is only clang-tidy that makes it a "must", while in general it is just a "should"